# javascript regex of a javascript string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a javascript string, with a regular expression, that is a string enclosed by single quote and can only contain a backslashed single quote.

The examples string that i would match are like the following:

```
'abcdefg'
'abc\'defg'
'abc\'de\'fg'
```

Comment: Can the string contain anything other than alpha chars and escaped single-quote?

Answer (score 2):

This is the regex that matches all valid JavaScript literal string (that is surrounded by single quote `'`) and reject all invalid ones. Note that **strict** mode is assumed.

```
/'(?:[^'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]|\\(?:['"\\bfnrtv]|[^\n\r\u2028\u2029'"\\bfnrtvxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})|\\(?:\n|\r\n|\r(?!\n)|[\u2028\u2029]))*'/
```

Or a shorter version:

```
/'(?:[^'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]|\\(?:[^\n\rxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\n|\r\n?))*'/
```

The regex above is based on the definition of `StringLiteral` (ignoring the double quoted version) specified in ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition published in June 2011.

The regex for the JavaScript literal string surrounded with double quote `"` is almost the same:

```
/"(?:[^"\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]|\\(?:[^\n\rxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\n|\r\n?))*"/
```

---

Let's dissect the monster (the longer version, since it is direct translation from the grammar):

- A `StringLiteral` (ignoring the double quote version) starts and ends with `'`, as it can be seen in the regex. In between the quotes is an optional sequence of `SingleStringCharacter`. This explains the `*` - 0 or more characters.
- `SingleStringCharacter` is defined as:

  ```
  SingleStringCharacter ::
         SourceCharacter but not one of ' or \ or LineTerminator
         \ EscapeSequence
         LineContinuation
  ```

  `[^'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]` corresponds to the first rule

  `\\(?:['"\\bfnrtv]|[^\n\r\u2028\u2029'"\\bfnrtvxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})` corresponds to the second rule

  `\\(?:\n|\r\n|\r(?!\n)|[\u2028\u2029])` corresponds to the third rule
- Let's look at the first rule: `SourceCharacter but not one of ' or \ or LineTerminator`. This first rule deals with "normal" characters.

  `SourceCharacter` is any Unicode unit.

  `LineTerminator` is Line Feed `<LF>` (`\u000A` or `\n`), Carriage Return `<CR>` (`\u000D` or `\r`), Line Separator `<LS>` (`\u2028`) or Paragraph Separator `<PS>` (`\u2029`).

  So we will just use a negative character class to represent this rule: `[^'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]`.
- For the second rule, which deals with escape sequences, you can see `\` before `EscapeSequence`, as it appears in the regex. As for `EscapeSequence`, this is its grammar (strict mode):

  ```
  EscapeSequence ::
          CharacterEscapeSequence
          0 [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]
          HexEscapeSequence
          UnicodeEscapeSequence
  ```

  `['"\\bfnrtv]|[^\n\r\u2028\u2029'"\\bfnrtvxu0-9]` is the regex for `CharacterEscapeSequence`. It can actually be simplified to `[^\n\r\u2028\u2029xu0-9]`

  The first part is `SingleEscapeCharacter`, which includes `'`, `"`, `\`, and for control characters `b`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `v`.

  The second part is `NonEscapeCharacter`, which is `SourceCharacter but not one of EscapeCharacter or LineTerminator`. `EscapeCharacter` is defined as `SingleEscapeCharacter`, `DecimalDigit` or  `x` (for hex escape sequence) or `u` (for unicode escape sequence).

  `0(?![0-9])` is the regex for the second rule of `EscapeSequence`. This is for specifying null character `\0`.

  `x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}` is the regex for `HexEscapeSequence`

  `u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}` is the regex for `UnicodeEscapeSequence`
- The third rule deals with string that spans multiple lines. Let's look at the grammar of `LineContinuation` and other related:

  ```
  LineContinuation ::
          \ LineTerminatorSequence

  LineTerminatorSequence :: 
          <LF> 
          <CR> [lookahead ∉ <LF> ]
          <LS>
          <PS>
          <CR> <LF>
  ```

  `\\(?:\n|\r\n|\r(?!\n)|[\u2028\u2029])` corresponds to the above grammar.

Comment: Umm, seems weird because those regex allow `var str = '''` or `var str = """` but they shouldn't... :/

Comment: Okay so, after digging a bit, `var str = '''` is allowed because your two regexes don't have ^ and $ to specify start and end. 
So, this one is "better" I think: `^"(?:[^"\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]|\\(?:[^\n\rxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\n|\r\n?))*"$|^'(?:[^'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]|\\(?:[^\n\rxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\n|\r\n?))*'$`

It handles both '' and "" strings :)

Comment: @Leiko: `'''` cannot be matched by the regex above. You probably get a match because `''` is considered a match. Adding anchors or not depend on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
/'(?:[^'\\]|\\'|\\(?!'))*'/
```

Test it in your console:

```
/'(?:[^'\\]|\\'|\\(?!'))*'/.exec("'abc\\\'de\\\'fg'")
```

It'll match

- Any number of characters that are:

  - `NOT ' or \` (except)
  - `\'` (or)
  - `\` (not followed by `'`)

If you want it to match the entire string, use the `^` start-of-string and `$` end-of-string markers:

```
/^'(?:[^'\\]|\\'|\\(?!'))*'$/
```

... which will match `'string'`, `'string\'s are awesome'` but not `'string's are awesome'` or `'string's`

Comment: Good catch, fixed the answer. Now just one `*` so it doesn't backtrack, and matches an empty string. Also changed to a non-capturing group. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

it's not that hard...

Also, you need to detect some other possible chars sequences like `\n`, `\r` or `\\`, breaking a line without escaping is not valid in javascript, you must use the `\n` sequence.

```
/^'([^\\'\n\r]|\\'|\\n|\\r|\\\\)*'$/
```

In execution:

```
var sample = ["'abcdefg'", // Valid
              "'abc\\'defg'", // Valid
              "'abc\\'de\\'fg'", // Valid
              "'abc\\'\\r\\nde\\'fg'", // Valid
              "'abc\\'\r\nde\\'fg'", // Invalid
              "'abc'def'" // Invalid
             ];
for(var i = 0; i < sample.length; i++)
    console.log(sample[i].match( /^'([^\\'\n\r]|\\'|\\n|\\r|\\\\)*'$/ ));
```

1. `^` tell to the matcher that the next condition must match the begining of the string
2. `'` will match the `'` delimiter
3. `(` opens a group
4. `[^\\'\n\r]` matches anything different from `\` and `'`, and will not match the special `\n` and `\r` characters
5. `|` if the condition above didn't match anything, the right side of `|` will be tested
6. `\\'` will match `\'`
7. `\\n` will match a `\n` literal string
8. `|\\r` or will match a `\r` literal string
9. `|\\\\` or will match a `\\` literal string
10. `)*` close the group and allow it to repeat multiple times and allow it to do not exist (empty string for example)
11. `'` will match the final `'` delimiter
12. `$` tell to the matcher that this must be the and of the string

Comment: but this string 'abc'def' is matched despite it is not valid

Comment: still easy to fix, I've changed the answer a little, just added `^` and `$`, now bad formations will not match

Comment: This undergenerates the possible string literals in JavaScript. Another problem is performance: `*` after `[^\\']` can be removed to reduce backtracking.

Comment: actually I disagree that `[^\\']*` will cause performance issue because it will match every character up to a `'` or `\ ` char, so in a string `'12345'` `[^\\']*` will match 5 chars in a row (5 ticks), than fail (1 tick) and process `\\'` that will also fail (1 tick) and leave the group with about 7 ticks. if the `*` wasn't there it would match 1 char (1 tick) process the group (1 tick) match other char and do this 5 times up to leave the group with about 12 ticks

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior: The performance problem happens when the input string fails to match. http://jsperf.com/regex-star-in-star

Comment: @nhahtdh yet I don't agree, if the string fails to match it would leave that group with `matchedLength + 6` ticks, if the `*` wasn't there would be `(matchedLength * 2) + 5`, causing performance issues when the string matches

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior: Just run the jsperf on your browser to test.

Comment: @nhahtdh I didn't see the jsperf link, yes, you are right, there's a performance issue when the string don't match.. I also did a test http://jsperf.com/js-regex and without `*` was a little faster when the string didn't match and with or without have nearly the same results but without being a little faster. Thank you for showing me this, I would never know that.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

<strike>/^'([a-z]*(?:\')?[a-z])+'$/</strike>

See example [here](http://regexr.com?333av)

```
str = 'abc\'de\'fg';

match = str.match(/^([a-z\\']+)$/g);
```

Tested in Firebug console. Works with or without the escape chars.

Comment: This is not a JavaScript RegEx

Comment: Then why do the tags say `javascript` and `regex`?

Comment: I meant your answer is not a JavaScript compatible RegEx, returns `null`. JavaScript regex's have slightly different notation than regex for other languages.

Comment: Javascript string can't contain numbers ? Why `[a-z]` only ? Plus, this regex allows `var str = '''`

Comment: @Leiko I initially asked the OP if the string could contain anything other than alpha chars and backslashed single quotes but didn't receive a reply, therefore I took the provided examples at face value. Also, `var str = '''` is not a valid string unless you escape the middle quote.

Comment: @garyh have a look at the last comment I made on __nhahtdh__ answer :)

Comment: @Leiko I did. Wouldn't fancy maintaining that.