# regex approach for extracting strings surrounded with double quotes

Tags: c#, regex

I have a search string that is getting passed

> Eg: "a+b",a, b, "C","d+e",a-b,d

I want to filter out all sub strings surrounded by double quotes("").
In above sample Output should contain:

> "a+b","C","d+e"

Is there a way to do this without looping?

Also I then need to extract a string without above values to do further processing

> Eg: a,b,a-b,d

Any suggestions on how to do this with minimal performance impact?

Thank you in advance for all your comments and suggestions

Comment: Can you explain why looping is disallowed? There are tons of ways of doing this if you allow a loop. Also, will you be packaging up this to send it to external code, or will your "further processing" be the same process?

Comment: It is possible but what is the format of the quoted string? Do you allow `"` to be escaped in the quoted string? Do you allow specifying new line `\n`?

Comment: You can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13800082/1400768 It is a regex to match or validate (since it is capable of generating the exact set of) JavaScript string literals. You need to have a clear specification before you can write any regex.

Comment: Guvante -: I know it is possible to write this with looping and still I am trying to identify alternative ways of doing it. Further processing means some additional things I perform based on the output of this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't say anything about how exactly you want your output (do you need to keep the commas and extra whitespace? Is it comma delimited to begin with? Let's assume that it is NOT comma delimited and you are just trying to remove the occurences of the "xyz":

```
    string strRegex = @"""([^""])+""";
    string strTargetString = @" ""a+b"",a, b, ""C"",""d+e"",a-b,d";
    string strOutput = Regex.Replace(strTargetString, strRegex, x => "");
```

Will remove all of the items (leaving the extra commas and whitespace).

If you are trying to do something where you need each individual match then you might want to try:

```
var y = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(strTargetString, strRegex) select m.Value).ToList<string>();
y.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

To get the list of items without the surrounding quotes, you could either reverse the regex pattern OR use the replace method in the first code sample and then split on the commas, trimming white space (again, assuming you are splitting on commas which it sounds like you are)

Answer (score 0):

First, add a comma to the end of your output:

```
"a+b",a, b, "C","d+e",a-b,d,
```

Then, use this regular expression:

```
((?<quoted>\".+?\")|(?<unquoted>.+?)),\s*
```

*Now you have 2 problems. Kidding!*

You'll have to find a way of extracting the matches without using a loop, but at least they are separated into quoted and unquoted strings by using the group. You could use a lamdba expression to pull the data out and join it, one each for quoted and unquoted, but it's just doing a loop behind the scenes, and may add more overhead than a simple for loop. It sounds like you're trying to eek out performance here, so time and test each method to see what gives the best results.