# How can I split a command string using regex

Tags: regex

I have to split a command string into segments using regex. I am looking for a very basic parser to create some custom functions, for example I have this command:

```
rm --remove all --keep some --but-not *.php --or-like "?-imp-*.*"
```

Now I want to split this string into multiple segments each containing the argument name and value, e.g.

```
rm
--remove all
--keep some
--but-not *.php
--or-like "?-imp-*.*"
```

So I can further split each segment off blank space and have the argument name and value separated.

I am not good at RegEx. So far I've written this Regex to extract the argument and value part only but it does not match the words at end of string or those with special characters like **`*`** and **`?`**

**Regex**

```
(?<=\s)--([^--]*)(?=(\s--))
```

and then I grab the name of command by

```
(^\w+)
```

Any thought on this ?

Comment: Does it all really have to be done with a single regex? You could just split from spaces, loop through the result and combine anything that starts with `--` with the next element (if the next element doesn't start with `--`).

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I don't think this is a job for (a single) regex. There should be existing library for this.

Comment: @beny23 Does language matters for Regex ? I want to use it in javascript and in a shell script as well.

Comment: @Juhana splitting into array and joining the elements does not seems reliable to me. It might fail in some cases.

Comment: It's *far* more reliable than regex...

Comment: @Gufran: Language does matter if the solution is regex, since the level of support is different between languages. If you want to use regex, you need to define the set of allowed characters in each token, in the level of detail of a standard (this is also useful when you do non-regex solution).

Comment: Thanks, right now I am sticking to Juhana's solution. Still looking for a more reliable way though.

Answer (score 1):

Example implementation in Javascript:

```
var match,
    str = 'rm --remove all --keep some --but-not *.php --or-like "?-imp\'\'-*.*"',
    args = [],
    reg = /\s--(\S+)\s+((["']).*?[^\\]\3|\S+)/g;

while ( match = reg.exec( str ) ) {
    args.push( [ match[1], match[2] ] );
}

console.log( args );

/* 
    [ [ "remove", "all" ], [ "keep", "some" ],
      [ "but-not", "*.php" ], [ "or-like", ""?-imp-*.*"" ] ]
 */
```

Note: this is not intended to be fully watertight and it requires that the format of a command is validated first.

Known limitation: an argument's value may not start with a quote mark and not have a closing quote mark, e.g. vales such as `"` and `'n` will break the parse.

Comment: `[^\3]` --> You cannot do this. It will match any character, except for the character with ASCII code 3.

Comment: Same problem as Billy Moon's solution regarding the quoted text, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh. Added known limitation. Further criticisms appreciated.

Comment: You can have a look at this (don't copy over, though, since the OP's requirement can be different): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799773/javascript-regex-of-a-javascript-string/13800082#13800082

Comment: @nhahtdh. `"'ab\'c'".match( /'(?:[^'\\\n\r\u2028\u2029]|\\(?:[^\n\rxu0-9]|0(?![0-9])|x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\n|\r\n?))*'/ ); // "'ab'"` Not sure how that helps here, or how it is better than what I have used above for this use case.

Comment: `"'ab\'c'"` contains `'ab'c'`, which is not a valid string as a whole. My regex correctly match only `'ab'`. `"'ab\\'c'"` will contain `'ab\'c'`, which is a valid string as a whole, and my regex correctly recognize it.

Comment: It will allow `"` to be specified in double quoted string `"`, by the use of escape \, and \ can be used to escape itself also \\.

Comment: @nhahtdh. Amended to allow escaped quotes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use regex for parsing, but regex should be used for tokenising.

Having said that, here is an imperfect regex that matches your scenario (but not all use cases)

Implemented in javascript...

```
str = 'rm --remove all --keep some --but-not *.php --or-like "?-imp-*.*"'   
regex = /(^\w+\b|--[\w-]+(\s([\w*.]+|".+?"))?)/g
res = str.match(regex)
// ['rm','--remove all','--keep some','--but-not *.php','--or-like "?-imp-*.*"']
```

Each item will need further processing to split into keys and values.

Comment: I feel jealous of you guys :( Thanks for the help, I find this one much better than other solutions.

Comment: @Gufran: Since the answer doesn't state the assumption: command is assumed to only contain `A-Z`,`a-z`,`0-9`,`_` (command is allowed to be something like `234__9`). The name of the switch is assumed to only contain `A-Z`,`a-z`,`0-9`,`_` and `-` (allowed to be this `---`). The value can either be without quote or with quote. If without quote, it can only contain `A-Z`,`a-z`,`0-9`,`_`, and `*` and `.`. If with quote, it can contain any character besides new line, but the problem is that you won't be able to specify `"` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would use library which implements GetOpt for javascript for that purpose (otherwise you're reinventing the wheel):

A quick google search brought up the following:

- http://code.google.com/p/v8cgi/source/browse/trunk/lib/getopt.js?r=447
- http://github.com/davepacheco/node-getopt
- https://npmjs.org/package/OptionParser

Note, I have not tried any of these.