# Regex to find information in PHP function

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on a regex but I'm not able to fix it.

I'm scanning documents (.php) with PHP and I'm looking for: `$__this('[TEXT]')` or `$__this("[TEXT]")`

So my question is: can somebody help me with a regex that searches in a string for: `$__this('[TEXT]')` or `$__this("[TEXT]")` and gives me `[TEXT]`

**UPDATE (with answer, thanks to @Explosion Pills):**

```
$string = '$__this("Foo Bar<br>HelloHello")';
preg_match('/\$__this\(([\'"])(.*?)\1\)/xi', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Even if the text is given back, you still need to do extra processing to get back the actual string, though.

Comment: You can use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php to tokenize the PHP file into PHP tokens. The rest should not be that hard.

Comment: You would probably need something like this: \$__this\(('|")\[(\w+)\]('|")\)

Comment: why would you want to scan PHP code like that? Please tell me you're not planning on writing a PHP program that modifies other PHP programs? That's a scary thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match('/
    \$__this # just $__this.  $ is meta character and must be escaped
    \(       # open paren also must be escaped
    ([\'"])  # open quote (capture for later use).  \' is needed in string
    (\[      # start capture.  open bracket must also be escaped
    .*?      # Ungreedily capture whatever is between the quotes
    \])      # close the open bracket and end capture
    \1       # close the quote (captured earlier)
    \)       # close the parentheses
/xi'         # ignore whitespace in pattern, allow comments, case insensitive
, $document, $matches);
```

The captured text will be in `$matches[2]`.  This assumes one possible capture per line.  If you need more, use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: This work if assuming all the text has format `[something here]`, but I think `[]` is just some sort of marking saying that that part can be anything. The question is quite unclear on this point.

Comment: @nhahtdh if the `[]` are not *actually* a part of the string, then you can simply remove them from my pattern.  I thought they were specifically there, though.  Does that make my answer unworthy of an upvote?

Comment: If the text contain `'"`, and you also remove `[]`, then your answer worth a down vote.

Comment: Nhahtdh is right.
This works:
$string = '$__this("[TEXT]")';
But I want also to get (for example): 
$string = '$__this("Foo Bar")';
PS:
I will update this question when I've got it :-)

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't understand what you mean.  Are you telling me to change something?  I will remove the `\[` and `\]`.  What do you mean if it contain `'"`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: For example `"text in \"quote\""`

Comment: @ExplosionPills: I am not sure about PHP, but this is a regex for Javascript literal string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13800082/1400768

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
preg_match('/\$__this(?:(\'|")\((.+?)\)\1)/', $string);
```

**explanation:**

```
(?-imsx:\$__this(?:(\'|")\((.+?)\)\1))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  __this                   '__this'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \'                       '''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You're missing the parentheses and brackets

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that will catch strings with quotes and apostrophes in them as well.

```
$txt = "
blah blah blah
blah \$_this('abc') blah
blah \$_this('a\"b\"c') blah balah \$_this('a\"b\"c\'')
\$_this(\"123\");\$_this(\"1'23\") \$_this(\"1'23\\\"\")
";

  $matches = array();
  preg_match_all('/(?:\$_this\()(?:[\'"])(.*?[^\\\])(?:[\'"])(?:\))/im', $txt, $matches);
  print_r($matches[1]);
```