# Java Regex to match "string"

Tags: java, regex, lexical-analysis

I am creating a lexical from scratch and I am getting into the part of matching `(")[\\w]+(")`.
I have this regular expression `^(\")[\\w]+(\")$`, but it won't catch the string.

SSCCE:

```
Map<String, String> lexicalMap = new HashMap<>();
// add all regex to `lexicalMap` via `lexicalMap.put([regex], [tokentype])`

// Tokenize the string format of the syntax to `List<String> tokens`
// List<String> tokens contains ["string", "data", "=", "test"] on the syntax: string data = "test"
for(String element : tokens) {
    for(String regex : lexicalMap.keySet()) {
        if(element.matches(regex))
            System.out.print(lexicalMap.get(regex) + " ");
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

REGEXs:

```
identifier = ^[\\w]+$
operator = ^(\\=)$
string = ^(\")[\\w]+(\")$ // THE PROBLEM
keyword = ^(string)$
```

Here is the case input/ouput I am following:

INPUT:

```
"test"
""
test
string data = "test"
```

OUTPUT:

```
string
string
identifier
keyword identifier operator string
```

---

UPDATED: 02/22/2013

- Added SSCCE segment.

Comment: Show us your code. How are you doing the match?

Comment: I have added my SSCCE on how I am doing the match.

Comment: I guess your tokens should contain: `["string", "data", "=", "\"test\""]``. Note how I stored `"test"`

Comment: That's what I taught. But what would happen if another case input would follow like `\"data\"`. Basing on how you replaced `"` to `\"`, the added case input would return `\"\"data\"\"`. And this would result to `string identifier string`

Comment: wait wait. `\"data\"` is not a string. If it would have been like - `"\"data\""`, then that is a string. And that would be stored like - `\"\\\"data\\\"\"`. You first need to be sure of what all kinds of input you are getting?

Comment: Can you post your snippet on this approach? Your already close on giving me the answer [I guess]. Kindly include how you we're able to replace " to \".

Comment: You would have to do much more work to make this program work completely. The problem is, a `keyword` is also a valid identifier. So, it will match two regexes in `Map`. And I would say, you should not match a keyword with regex. Since keywords in Java are fixed, so better to have a `Set` of all those keywords, and match against that set.

Comment: So, first test for a `keyword`, if found, then ok, if not, go with matching an identifier with regex, then an operator (Again, store all the operators in a `Set`).. Like so, you can make your code even better, and scalable. But, here another problem. `String` is not a keyword in Java. It's a class. So, you are not considering that thing.

Comment: Okay. But how about the string regex? Do I need to replace all " to \"?

Comment: When you store a string as a string, it would be stored like - `"\"test\""`, because you need to store those `"` at the ends too. So, in your regex, you need to match `\"` too at the ends.

Comment: @Dr.Java: Please review **the grammar for the format of the string**. Each language has slightly different grammar for the format of the string (and also the semantics). You may have forgotten about the cases of `\n`, `\f`, `\u2342`, `\x20`, `\0`, multiline string, etc. You may want to take a look at [this to see how complex a regex for matching a string literal can be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799773/javascript-regex-of-a-javascript-string/13800082).

Comment: The `[]` in `[\\w]+` are unnecessary.

Comment: Is the OUPTUT you show the desired output, or is it what you are actually getting? If what you are getting is not correct please show the cases it fails on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what happened but after changing the regular expression from `^(\")[\\w]+(\")$` to `^(\")[\\w]*(\")?$` it worked correctly.

Comment: It is going to break badly with a simple string such as `"@"` or `"Enter a number: "`

Comment: Adding `?` to `(\")` makes the `"` optional, are you sure that is what you want? `\\w+` means one or more word characters, `\\w*` means _zero_ or more. The brackets in your regex seem pointless, so `"^\"\\w*\"$"`, though it only allows word characters between the quotes.

Comment: @MikeM true that making the second `"` can destroy the string grammar. I just need to have an additional procedure to validate the grammar among the string tokens.