# javascript regex to match anything between single quotes, double quotes and regex slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match anything between either double quotes, single quotes, or regex slashes, basically anything that isn't tokenized by javascript as a string or regex. So far what I came up with is:

```
/"[^\\"\n]*(\\"[^\\"\n]*)*"|'[^\\'\n]*(\\'[^\\'\n]*)*'|\/[^\\\/\n]*(\\\/[^\\\/\n]*)*\//
```

But there are a couple of problems with this as you can see [**here**](http://goo.gl/4Yn9pR)

### http://goo.gl/4Yn9pR

Basically this shouldn't match `1+2/3+4/5` since it isn't a regex. Also
`Dont match "Match here\\" Dont match"` should match the first part and not the second (thats true for single quotes and regexes too)

How should this be written?

Edit: If it's not possible differentiate between `1+2/3+4/5`, `/*comment*/` and `/regex/` using regular expressions, how would I just solve the `Dont match "Match here\\" Dont match"` problem

Comment: You cannot differentiate between `1+2/3+4/5`, `/*comment*/` and `/regex/` using regular expressions only - you'll need a proper parser.

Comment: @thg435 Noted, see edit

Comment: It is possible to match a JavaScript string literal with JavaScript's RegExp. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799773/javascript-regex-of-a-javascript-string/13800082#13800082 (I write it from the specs, so it is guarantee to not over-accept or over-reject). It is guaranteed to match a valid JS String, but it is not guaranteed to correctly match all JS String in arbitrary JS source code (e.g. string-like sequence in comment).

Answer (score 0):

The trick to match c-alike escaped strings is like this:

```
" (\\. | [^"]) * "
```

That is,

```
 - quote
 - repeat (
    - one escaped char
    - or not a quote
   )
  - quote
```

Similarly with single quotes. Illustration in python since JS regexes are ugly:

```
import re

test = r"""
    foo "bar" and "bar\"bar" and "bar\\bar" and "bar \\"
    foo 'bar' and 'bar\'bar' and 'bar\\bar' and 'bar \\'
"""

rr = r"""(?x)
    " (\\. | [^"]) * "
    |
    ' (\\. | [^']) * '
"""

print re.sub(rr, '@@', test)

> foo @@ and @@ and @@ and @@
> foo @@ and @@ and @@ and @@
```

It might be necessary to add newlines to the `[^"]` group.

Do note that this expression is quite forgiving and allows many constructs that aren't valid javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13800082/989121 for the complete and accurate implementation.

Comment: What's up with the spaces? And `"\x4"` is not a valid string in JS.

Comment: Slight speed improvement change `(\\. | [^"])` to `([^"] | \\.)`

Comment: @MosheK: no! `[^"]` will consume slashes, leaving the escapes unparsed.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I added a note to the answer. My point was to give the OP an idea, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I was very close. Here's the solution:

```
/"[^\\"\n]*(\\["\\][^\\"\n]*)*"|'[^\\'\n]*(\\['\\][^\\'\n]*)*'|\/[^\\\/\n]*(\\[\/\\][^\\\/\n]*)*\//
```

#### [DEMO](http://goo.gl/32n3WE)

It's very similar to thg435 answer but I think it's a little more performent because it doesn't backtrack as much

What I was missing was when looking for an escaped quote, I should have also been looking for an escaped backslash too, so i changed `\\"` to `\\["\\]` As opposed to thg435's answer which looks at anything after a backslash which while valid can use up more states in the regex engine