# How do I use Regex to process a template and to ignore escaped characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been writing a template processor for some time, and I decided to modify it to support new features I have planned. One of these features is ignoring escaped characters. Unfortunately, I have no idea what I'm doing (this is a learning endeavour).

To start with, I wrote a regular expression to process this test string, using negative lookaheads. It didn't seem to work quite right, though - it would capture the leading space, and I'm not sure why. It would also process the string as normal if there was only a backslash on the first bracket, rather than on the first and last.

```
Lorum \{#variable} ipsum {#variable\} dolor \{#variable} ismet {#variable} lorum ipsum.
```

This is the expression used:

```
(?![\\])[^\\][{}]#([^{}]+)}
```

If this is not easily done with pure regular expressions, I am using JavaScript, so other options are certainly open. I do not, however, want to use a template engine, as this is an educational project.

This same code is to be used as a basis for several other matches, so it is important that it can also work for `{%RandomOne|RandomTwoWith{#var}|RandomThree}` and for (although I understand this is far more complex, so ideally it will be processed separately) `{?if 1=1}First {#var}{?elseif 1=2}{%RandomOne|RandomTwoWith{#var}|RandomThree}{?else}Blank{?endif}`

I am fully aware that this use of regular expressions is likely sub-optimal, and I would be happy (in fact, eager) to hear of a more efficient way of processing this data. It seems to be the if statements that are the most complicated to process in this case.

Comment: Regexes could do the job if you had access to, say, PCRE... But JavaScript regexes are just too weak for this. The real issue here is the nested braces.

Comment: Ignoring escape character is usually easy, even with the most basic flavor of regex. A complex (and real) example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799773/javascript-regex-of-a-javascript-string/13800082#13800082. The format is `delimiter (non-escape-character | escape-sequence)* delimiter`